# Migrate Flutter app: realtime db to firestore

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am migrate flutter app from Firebase realtime database to firestore. I have trouble with update this code in chat app because firestore no have FirebaseAnimatedList.

Old code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text(“chat“),
    ),
    body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
                query: reference,
                sort: (a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key),
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                reverse: true,
                itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                    Animation<double> animation, int x) {
                  return new ChatMessage(
                      snapshot: snapshot, animation: animation);
                },
              ),
            ),
```

New code (but give me errors):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text(“chat"),
    ),
    body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: reference.snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  return snapshot.hasData? new ListView(
                    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    reverse: true,
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    children: snapshot.data.documents.map(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                      return new ChatMessage(
                      snapshot: snapshot,
                      animation: animation,
                      );
                  })
        ),
```

reference:

```
final reference = Firestore.instance.collection('messages');
```

Any help?

I have look up: 
[Firestore StreamBuilder with nested AnimatedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681823/firestore-streambuilder-with-nested-animatedlist)
[How to bind a Firestore documents list to a Dropdown menu in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823542/how-to-bind-a-firestore-documents-list-to-a-dropdown-menu-in-flutter)
[How to listen for document changes in Cloud Firestore using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471309/how-to-listen-for-document-changes-in-cloud-firestore-using-flutter)

Update:

Thanks everyone for response! I make some changes.

New code:

```
child: new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: reference.snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('loading...');
                      return new ListView(
                          children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                      return new ChatMessage(
                      snapshot: snapshot,
                      animation: animation,
                      );
                      }).toList(),
                      );
                    }
                ),
                ),
```

Now only error is in animation. I have error: `undefined name 'animation'`

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: @UpaJah For 'snapshot.data.documents.map(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)'. Error: 'Function expressions can't be named.'

Answer (score 0):

try using ListView.builder ..

```
  new Flexible(
      child: new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: reference.snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                reverse: false,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ChatMessage(
                      animation, snapshot.data.documents[index], index);
                });
          }))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have try your code but it give many error. I have now update my code above. Now only error is where to define 'animation'.

Answer (score 0):

Missing a bracket:

`children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {`

Comment: Thanks! This help, but I still have error. I have update in edit above.

Comment: You need to define animation somewhere if you need an animation. Try and get it working without an animation first.